# Make each "li" from json it's own link?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Does anybody know how to make the text that appears in the following "li" both a link and also customizable through CSS? I have been unable to drop the text-decoration, change font style, color, etc. I've tried changing the style of the "tree" id but I was only able to change font size.

While both are important the link is crucial. Each "li" that is returned needs to be its own dynamically generated link. I've tried about 10 different ways now and I can't quite seem to get it to work.

```
 <script>

function to_ul(id) {

    var ul = document.createElement("ul");

  for (var i=0, n=id.length; i<n; i++) {

      var branch = id[i];

      var li = document.createElement("li");

        var text = document.createTextNode(branch.trackName);

        li.appendChild(text);

        ul.appendChild(li);

    }

    return ul;

}

function renderTree() {

  var treeEl = document.getElementById("tree");
        var treeObj = {"root":[{"id":"1","trackName":"Whippin Post"},{"id":"2","trackName":"Sweet Caroline"},{"id":"3","trackName":"Tears in Heaven"},{"id":"4","trackName":"Ain't She Sweet"},{"id":"5","trackName":"Octopus' Garden"},{"id":"6","trackName":"Teen Spirit"},{"id":"7","trackName":"Knockin on Heaven's Door"}]};

    treeEl.appendChild(to_ul(treeObj.root));

}

</script>

</head>

<body onload="renderTree()">

<div id="tree"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

*UPDATE*

```
<script>
function to_ul(id) {
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");

  for (var i=0, n=id.length; i<n; i++) {

    var branch = id[i];

    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = "<a href=" + "'#'" + "class='listAnchor'" + "onclick='changeText()'" + ">" + branch.trackName + "</a>"
    ul.appendChild(li);

    function changeText(){
    document.getElementById('player-digital-title').innerHTML = branch.trackFile;
    }
    }

    return ul;  
}

function renderTree() {
  var treeEl = document.getElementById("player-handwriting-title");

        var treeObj = {"root":[{"id":"1","trackName":"Whippin Post","trackFile":"test1.wma"},{"id":"2","trackName":"Sweet Caroline","trackFile":"test2.wma"},{"id":"3","trackName":"Tears in Heaven","trackFile":"test3.wma"},{"id":"4","trackName":"Ain't She Sweet","trackFile":"test4.wma"},{"id":"5","trackName":"Octopus' Garden","trackFile":"test5.wma"},{"id":"6","trackName":"Teen Spirit","trackFile":"test6.wma"},{"id":"7","trackName":"Knockin on Heaven's Door","trackFile":"test7.wma"}]};

    treeEl.appendChild(to_ul(treeObj.root));


    treeEl.appendChild(to_ul(treeObj.root));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" class="genre" onclick="renderTree()">Click here</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="#" id="player-handwriting-title"></a>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="player-digital-title"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, you want the <li> style to change when someone clicks on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a "link" presumably you want an anchor element inside each li element, and for the a elements you'd want to have `href` attributes that you don't seem to have in your data. But by way of example, assuming you want to use the `id` as the `href` you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var treeObj = {"root":[{"id":"1","trackName":"Whippin Post"},{"id":"2","trackName":"Sweet Caroline"},{"id":"3","trackName":"Tears in Heaven"},{"id":"4","trackName":"Ain't She Sweet"},{"id":"5","trackName":"Octopus' Garden"},{"id":"6","trackName":"Teen Spirit"},{"id":"7","trackName":"Knockin on Heaven's Door"}]};

  var $ul = $("<ul></ul>");       
  $.each(treeObj.root,function(i,v) {
    $ul.append($("<li></li>").append(
                              $("<a></a>").attr("href",v.id).html(v.trackName)));
  });
  $("#tree").append($ul);
});
```

Your question was tagged with "jQuery", so I've gone ahead and created the list (with anchors inside each li) using jQuery. The `$.each()` "loop" iterates through each element in the `treeObj.root` array, creating an a element with the `id` and `trackName`, appending that to a new li element, and appending that to a ul element. After the `.each()` finishes the new ul is appended to your tree div.

As far as styling the links, that's up to you to do the CSS you want, but since you mention dropping the text decoration you may want to start with something like this:

```
#tree a { text-decoration : none; }
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/B2Zsv/

(If that code and output as shown in the fiddle isn't the sort of thing you're looking for I suggest you update your question to show the desired output html that you want to generate.)

**UPDATE**

The following variation on my original code stores the track names as attributes on the anchors created, and then retrieves them on click.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var treeObj = {"root":[{"id":"1","trackName":"Whippin Post","trackFile":"test1.wma"},{"id":"2","trackName":"Sweet Caroline","trackFile":"test2.wma"},{"id":"3","trackName":"Tears in Heaven","trackFile":"test3.wma"},{"id":"4","trackName":"Ain't She Sweet","trackFile":"test4.wma"},{"id":"5","trackName":"Octopus' Garden","trackFile":"test5.wma"},{"id":"6","trackName":"Teen Spirit","trackFile":"test6.wma"},{"id":"7","trackName":"Knockin on Heaven's Door","trackFile":"test7.wma"}]};

    var $ul = $("<ul></ul>");       
    $.each(treeObj.root,function(i,v) {
        $ul.append(
            $("<li></li>").append( $("<a></a>").attr({
                "href":v.id,"data-file":v.trackFile}).html(v.trackName) )
        );
    });
    $("#tree").append($ul);

    $("#tree a").click(function() {
      var trackname = $(this).html(),
          filename = $(this).attr("data-file");

      // here add your code to do something with filename and/or trackname

      return false;
    });
});
```

As you can see my click handler doesn't actually do anything with the filename once it gets it (my updated demo http://jsfiddle.net/B2Zsv/3/ displays it), but that shows you how to get the right filename so from there you can figure out how to play it...

Comment: This is pretty close to what I am looking for. I updated the question because I need to link to the filename when I click on the li link. Unfortunately I wasn't able to get this example to work on my local machine. Is there something I'm missing migrating it from jsfiddle?

Comment: Other than having a container div with an id of "tree", everything needed to make the fiddle work is shown in my answer so I don't know what's going wrong for you on your local machine. Sorry, I don't have time to figure out how to make the files play for you, but I'll update my answer to show at least how to associate the file names with the links, and how to retrieve the file name when the link is clicked.

Comment: This solution worked great, thank you. Sorry it took so long for me to respond. I ended up building on this slightly so that when the list is produced by clicking a "genre".  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First off create the link in js:

```
function to_ul(id) {

  var ul = document.createElement("ul");

  for (var i=0, n=id.length; i<n; i++) {

    var branch = id[i];
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = "<a href='wherever' class='listAnchor'>" + branch.trackName + "</a>"
    ul.appendChild(li);

  }
  return ul;
}
```

and then style it in css:

```
<style>
  .listAnchor {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: All these answers were great but this one was the closest to what I was looking for. One more question though: I'm trying to make so when I click on the li the name of the file will produce in the "Now Playing" section and the song will play. I have updated the code above to represent this. I think I'm close but I can't call the trackFile from the json output correctly.

Comment: javascript does not have block scope so the variable `branch` will have changed by the time `changeText()` is called. My guess is it looks like no matter what you click on you are going to replace `player-digital-title` with `test7.wma`. But you should start another question for this because you will need to change a lot to fix it (as a rule of thumb, don't define functions inside loops, it is always trouble). If my answer helped you, you should accept it by clicking the checkmark :)

Answer (score 0):

To create an `a` element within the `li` elements, simply apply the same techniques as demonstrated in the code as you have it:

function to_ul(id) {

```
var ul = document.createElement("ul");

for (var i = 0, n = id.length; i < n; i++) {

    var branch = id[i];

    var li = document.createElement("li"),
        a = document.createElement('a'); // create the `a`
    a.href = "http://example.com/"; // set the `href`

    var text = document.createTextNode(branch.trackName);
    a.appendChild(text); // append text to the a
    li.appendChild(a); // append the a to the li

    ul.appendChild(li);

}

return ul;
```

}

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BZ7RX/).

To style that link, you can either use CSS in your document, or in an external stylesheet (as with any other CSS):

```
li a:link,
li a:visited {
    /* style the link's 'default' state */
}

li a:hover,
li a:active,
li a:focus {
    /* style the 'interactive' states of the links */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BZ7RX/1/).

You could, of course, simply apply the styles directly in the JavaScript that creates said elements, though this is needlessly expensive:

```
/* all the other stuff removed, for brevity */
    var li = document.createElement("li"),
        a = document.createElement('a'); // create the `a`
    a.href = "http://example.com/"; // set the `href`
    a.style.color = '#000';
    a.style.textDecoration = 'none';
    /* ...and other stuff... */
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BZ7RX/2/).

This approach, apart from being expensive, also lacks the ability to style the `:hover`, `:active`, `:visited` and `:focus` styles.